# Dplyr group_modify and anonymous functions

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Please have a look at the code below, where I have a data frame which I group and I then add a couple of summary statistics (I modified some examples I found online).
It works and it relies on the formula interface to specify the anonymous function, but whenever I tried to rewrite it as

function(x) bind_rows(x, ...)

I get an error because I do not specify at least two arguments. I simply want to make sure I can write this both ways (with and without the "~" notation).
Can anyone help me out and calculate df_out with an anonymous function without the formula interface?

Thanks!

```r
 library(tidyverse)



##Have a look at


## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831166/how-would-i-add-a-total-row-for-each-value-in-a-specific-column-that-does-calcu


## https://community.rstudio.com/t/add-specific-rows-to-create-new-row-using-r-dplyr/13137/2


df1 <- structure(list(month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), person = c("John", 
   "Jane", "Tim", "Cindy", "John", "Jane", "Tim", "Cindy"), total = c(7L, 
 18L, 20L, 11L, 18L, 13L, 15L, 9L), days_in_month = c(31L, 31L, 
  31L, 31L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                      -8L)) %>%
    as_tibble


df1
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   month person total days_in_month
#>   <int> <chr>  <int>         <int>
#> 1     1 John       7            31
#> 2     1 Jane      18            31
#> 3     1 Tim       20            31
#> 4     1 Cindy     11            31
#> 5     2 John      18            28
#> 6     2 Jane      13            28
#> 7     2 Tim       15            28
#> 8     2 Cindy      9            28


df_out <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(month, days_in_month) %>% 
    group_modify(~ bind_rows(.x, tibble(person = "Mean", total = mean(.x$total)),  tibble(person = "Mean2",
                                        total = mean(.x$total[.x$total>10])))   ) %>%
    ungroup



df_out
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    month days_in_month person total
#>    <int>         <int> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1     1            31 John     7  
#>  2     1            31 Jane    18  
#>  3     1            31 Tim     20  
#>  4     1            31 Cindy   11  
#>  5     1            31 Mean    14  
#>  6     1            31 Mean2   16.3
#>  7     2            28 John    18  
#>  8     2            28 Jane    13  
#>  9     2            28 Tim     15  
#> 10     2            28 Cindy    9  
#> 11     2            28 Mean    13.8
#> 12     2            28 Mean2   15.3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: what is your expected.  Not clear.  The `~ .x` is anonymous function call

Comment: I expect to have the same df_out, just using function(x) bind_rows(x, ....) instead of the "~" notation. I should have been clearer: I want to be able to write an anonymous function which does the same job without using the "~" notation.

Comment: From the docs: `If a function, it is used as is. It should have at least 2 formal arguments.

If a formula, e.g. ~ head(.x), it is converted to a function.

In the formula, you can use

. or .x to refer to the subset of rows of .tbl for the given group

.y to refer to the key, a one row tibble with one column per grouping variable that identifies the group` So an anonymous function needs to take two arguments, e.g. `function(group_df, key_df) { ... }`

Comment: ...but the idiom you're using is inadvisable; it's a thought process that comes from spreadsheets. The problem is that `Mean` and `Mean2` are not people. Much better to do `df1 %>% 
    group_by(month, days_in_month) %>% 
    summarise(Mean = mean(total),  Mean2 = mean(total[total > 10]))`, or `mutate` instead of `summarise` if the original data is still needed.

Comment: thanks, but do not think about the semantic of the data. It is just an example and do not worry about mean and mean2 not being people. I read the documentation, but I cannot find a way to make progress without the tilde notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the regular `function(x, y)` as the `.f` in `group_modify` specifies

> .f - If a function, it is used as is. It should have at least 2 formal arguments.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(month, days_in_month) %>% 
  group_modify(function(x, y) bind_rows(x,
        tibble(person = "Mean", total = mean(x$total)), 
        tibble(person = "Mean2",
               total = mean(x$total[x$total>10])))   ) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Perfect! This answers my question. I now understand my mistake: I need to provide a y variable even if I do not use it. In this case, the tilde notation is more logical and the function is created under the hood. Thanks.